# scanner hardware interfacing with openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr

When we are working in OCR (English OCR), then our input is an image which is taken from the camera or scanner, and then after processing it's converted into a text document. 
I would like to interface the scanner with openCV for OCR.  I have written code which converts an image into editable form, but in my code it takes an image which I have already saved in my PC. But now I want it to take an image that I scanned from the scanner, and then convert that image into editable form. How do I interface a scanner with OpenCV, to scan an image?

Comment: The question will be platform and OS specific. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319633/how-to-scan-images-using-digital-scanner-with-opencv

Comment: I used to work on OpenCV, and so far i remember, it only allows you to capture video/image from your stored files and camera. You should check out, if it allows scanner or not.

Comment: Linux: [SANE](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialScanners.html), Windows: [TWAIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TWAIN), [WIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Image_Acquisition), or [WPD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388998(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: If your scanner supports ethernet or wifi (meaning that it can send a file to a network folder on your local network), you can configure it to sent to a shared folder on your computer, so that your program could pick it up there.